# Attribute "integrity" not allowed on element "script" at this point

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, netbeans-8

I want to "decorate" my Website with Bootstrap, but when I paste the two tags for Bootstrap on my HTML file, it says that the attribute integrity is not allowed here. What do I do wrong? 
These are the Tags I did copy :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

And this is how it looks in conclusion:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
   </head>
    <body>
        <p>Name</p>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <p>Subject</p>
        <textarea></textarea>
         <p>Tel</p>
         <textarea></textarea>
         <p>E - Mail</p>
         <textarea></textarea>
        <p>Message</p>
        <textarea></textarea>
        <p><button>Submit</button></p>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser? I don't think the integrity attribute is compatible in IE or Safari. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity

Comment: Doesn't matter for now i think . The problem is that the Compiler in Netbeans shows the integrity attribute as an error.

Comment: Gotcha. Maybe Netbeans is showing the error because of the incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the `integrity` attribute isn't strictly necessary. It's just a "nice to have" to prevent hackers from changing the contents of the CDN file(s) **IF** those hackers manage to hack a major CDN like `maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com` (which in itself is very unlikely to happen).

So, at least during development, you can remove the `integrity` attribute without any problems and then add that in for the final production files.

Secondly, the alpha version of Bootstrap 4 is completely and totally **outdated** and should not be used anywhere. Use a fresh, current version of Bootstrap 4: https://getbootstrap.com

Answer (score -8):

I solved this issue by replacing

```
integrity='xyz'
```

with

```
style="integrity:'xyz'"
```

Comment: That doesn’s mean anything. Integrity is not a css property. You can just leave out the integrity attribute altogether.